# mysql - Right join not retriving correct data

Tags: mysql

I am storing the user activity in the table by start and end time , now i want to get all records from my subject table and matched records from log table.

This is my subject table
[image]

This is my log table
[image]

I want the output like this

[image]

I tried using some code but the records that only matched with log table is return as record, This is what i tried. Any help is appreciable.

```
SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, A.start_time, A.end_time)) AS prep_time,
                    B.subject_name,
                    A.subject_id
                FROM prep_learn_log A
                RIGHT JOIN prep_subject B ON A.subject_id = B.subject_id 
                    AND B.active = 'Y'
                WHERE A.user_id = '1' GROUP BY A.subject_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the WHERE clause

```
WHERE A.user_id = '1'
```

You are creating correctly the RIGHT JOIN but this condition is forzing to showthe row only if the Log table (renamed as A) is equal to 'Y'.
You need to change this condition for example:

```
SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, A.start_time, A.end_time)) AS prep_time,
                    B.subject_name,
                    A.subject_id
                FROM prep_learn_log A
                RIGHT JOIN prep_subject B ON A.subject_id = B.subject_id 
                    AND B.active = 'Y'
                WHERE COALESCE(A.user_id, '1') = '1' 
                GROUP BY A.subject_id
```

I

Answer (score 0):

The condition by left table in WHERE clause (`WHERE A.user_id = '1'`) converts your join to INNER. Move this condition from WHERE clause to ON clause.

```
SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, A.start_time, A.end_time)) AS prep_time,
       B.subject_name,
       A.subject_id
FROM prep_learn_log A
RIGHT JOIN prep_subject B ON A.subject_id = B.subject_id 
                         AND B.active = 'Y'
                         AND A.user_id = '1' 
GROUP BY A.subject_id
```